# ServiceStack.net equivalent for Java (or something that could interwork with ServiceStack)?

Tags: java, python, ruby, node.js, servicestack

I read about [ServiceStack.NET](http://www.servicestack.net/) and really liked it a lot (especially the fact that it is based on a messaging paradigm and implements the Data Transfer Objects pattern).

I would like to know if there is any framework for Java that comes close to what ServiceStack provides for .NET? Alternatively, do you know of any Java framework that can interwork with ServiceStack?

I am especially interested in the below features that ServiceStack.Net provides:

- Metadata pages for all registered formats With links to WSDLs, XSDs
- Support for JSON/JSONP, XML, JSV, CSV and SOAP on all end-points

And although I am looking for a framework that provides the above features on the JVM, I would also be interested in one of these platforms because I suspect that they could be used as intermediaries for interworking with the JVM world (i.e. the Facade pattern).

- Python
- Ruby
- node.js

Comment: To who ever thinking of recommending this question for closure, I feel this can be answered with references, or specific expertise and should not be closed.

Comment: For those who down voted, lets have a discussion to understand the reasons for down vote. I don't understand where else I can get help to learn more about frameworks which solve a particular problem.

Comment: Ask a question on Meta if you want to discuss.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Rachel and vote to reopen!

Comment: @Ramesh You're welcome, but it still needs 3 more votes from other community members to get reopened. If its not reopened in a few days, you can try to [edit] your question to rephrase it like I suggested on [your meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167120/158605), or posting an entirely new question. Good luck with it :)

Comment: I have rephrased the question significantly because I think that people are more likely to answer questions asking for technical info rather than questions asking for help. If there is a way to use ServiceStack from Java or even to interwork with Java, then this question should get some answers. Then, if you want more info, you would be better sending mail to the people who answer or to people working on the other projects.

Comment: @MichaelDillon Thanks for the edit. I have specifically asked for some frameworks because, I had access to those platforms such as GAE which is free which supports Java and python and PHP which is supported by my web host. But, now I have come to a point if there is any implementation in platform should also be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with http://www.servicestack.net/, however it seems to be a Web Application Framework built around Enterprise Integration Patterns (EIPs).

- [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) integrates with a lot of the services you mentioned and is also built around EIPs. A great place to start is [@Claus Isben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406429/)'s [Camel In Action](https://www.google.com/#q=camel+in+action) book.

In case you just want to build a web application, try:

- Many Java web applications are built with [Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) to great success. It has a lot of the features you're looking for, and I'm sure there is a lot of documentation for the integrations you're looking for.
- It seems like you're looking for a fully featured integration framework, but just in case you are looking for a much more lightweight approach, try [Jersey, the JAX-RS Reference Implementation](https://jersey.java.net/). It has [WADL support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#wadl) out of the box with the [sample application](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by using Apache CXF and Camel transport for cxf.  http://camel.apache.org/camel-transport-for-cxf.html